# How to trigger click events using hooks

Tags: hooks, actions

I'm using Gravity Forms and after submission I want to use its built-in action `add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );` to trigger a couple of click events from 2 different elements in that page. Is it possible? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's not really necessary to use php for this, but just `bind` will do the trick:

```
$(document).bind('gform_confirmation_loaded', function($){
    $("button").trigger("click");
});
```

And that's it! :)

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible (well, not without building super weird things). Action hooks are server side in PHP, clicks happen on the client side.

You should probably use JavaScript to run the actions when the form is submitted. With jQuery, this could be as easy as

```
jQuery("#formid").submit( function() {
    jQuery("#someButton").click();
});
```

Depending on what else you need to verify first.